# verb for dogs moving and dancing around dead corpses.

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

What is the verb for when dogs come moving and dancing around the corpses of other dead animals (like say, lions) and they look for food. They can't approach them when they're alive and in their might but they come along when they are dead and dance and gad in a cowardly manner. It is similar to when the battle is finished and soldiers start moving about looking for the injured to finish them off and check they are killed for sure. It has a cowardliness behind it. Even describing the manner in which they cowardly move and scamper for meat.

I'd appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The following works nicely,

## Skulk

> 1. Keep out of sight, typically with a sinister or cowardly motive
>    1.1  Move stealthily or furtively:

[ref: Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skulk)

The adjective is 'skulking'